# Java FileWriterfilewriet

Tags: java

Ребят объясните почему у меня не пишет с новой строки?

```
FileWriter statW = new FileWriter("statistics.md");
    statW.write(name+"\n"+years+" лет");
    statW.close();
```

Comment: Выводите \n в начале, тогда с новой строки и напишет.

Comment: В итоге имею:
Артём19 лет

Comment: в чем смотрите полученный файл?

Comment: В стандартном текстовике windows

Comment: @FussionBart для справки - [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Перевод_строки) по теме

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в место \n попробуйте \r\n. должно помочь

Comment: Помогло спасибо)